# Table with termistor models with alfa

Tags: thermistor

Hello I'm searching table with thermistors types and alfa (temperature coefficient). I need alfa for this formula :

```
Mt = 1 - alfa/100*(Tmax - 20)
```

I have some old calculations where for MMT-9 type thermistor alfa = 2,4. This is what table I'm searching thermistor types with alfa

Comment: Please provide a link to the specific thermistor you are interested in.

Comment: I'm searching for one. This is why I ask for a table.

Comment: You'll find that in the datasheets.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_a_Hole_in_My_Bucket - read the lyric.

Comment: I had look at datasheets, firstly there are too many thermistors, and I can check them all, secondly I don't see this parameter is there any formula with which I can calculate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't find that parameter, it can be calculated using the formula:

\$R = R_0 (1 + \alpha (T-T_0))\$ so

\$\alpha = {{R - R_0} \over {R_0 (T-T_0)}}\$

\$R\$ represents the value of thermistor at the temperature \$T\$. The same for \$R_0, T_0\$.

You can find an online calculator on [HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/restmp.html) (bottom of the page).

Looking in this [muRata catalog](http://www.murata.com/products/catalog/pdf/r44e.pdf) I can see that they are using a \$B\$ coefficient, which seems to be \$B = \alpha ^ {-1}\$

Comment: Nice and simple explanation :)